# Managing style sheets for partial views

Tags: css, html, frontend

Is it a bad idea to "hard code" style sheets in partial HTML views?

For small partial views, it seems preferable to having yet another external style sheet, the reference to which I have to keep track of *outside* the partial view

For clarification: I am not really talking about the same partial view that would get used many times across a single page - but rather about the same view that would be rendered on many different pages.

How *should* I manage style sheets for partial views?

Comment: So you created a Partial View that is only going to be loaded *once*... *ever*?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Not once _ever_. It gets reused by different pages. But yes, once per page.

Comment: Yup; That's "reuse"; therefore, you would be needlessly re-serving the same style sheets repeatedly.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: ... because it could be cached instead. I get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's best to put *all* styles for an entire site into a [single CSS file to speed performance](http://webdesign.about.com/od/speed/qt/use-one-external-css-file.htm). Separate the regions of the style-sheet for various components of your front end by clear comment blocks.

I have stylesheets with 800+ lines, with all declarations for a particular selector on a single line, that add up to 20-30k only.  It  gets downloaded only once, then it's cached for every page on your site. Make sure you manage your [expires header](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/05/high_performanc_2/). Avoid making multiple http requests with separate style sheets.